# How to create a new OBJECT TYPE in Oracle PL/SQL if it doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to declare a new OBJECT TYPE in PL/SQL to hold rows in a join query that only selects a few columns. I can create the TYPE just fine, but it becomes part of the schema.

Something like:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_objects WHERE LOWER(object_name) = 'my_custom_type') = 0 THEN
    CREATE TYPE my_custom_type AS OBJECT
    (
        ...
    );
    /
END IF;

DECLARE
    v_foo my_custom_type%TYPE;
BEGIN
    -- Do stuff with v_foo...
END;
/
```

**How can I check to see if the TYPE exists before creating it?**

Comment: Why not just `create or replace` it?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: I didn't even know that was an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need new SQL-type. You may create it using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count
    FROM user_objects
    WHERE LOWER(object_name) = 'my_custom_type';

    IF v_count = 0 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TYPE my_custom_type AS OBJECT (
            id      NUMBER(10),
            name    VARCHAR2(100)
        )';
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Ok. That at least puts me in a PL/SQL block where I can use an `IF` statement.

Comment: That seems to work, but I'm going to update your answer with some working code. Thanks!

Comment: I was opening a cursor and looping through it, and forgot I can SELECT INTO a list of variable names, which is what I ended using instead of this solution. Up-voted and marked it as the answer, because it does work.